# XSD to Java custom datatype

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have xsd which contain the following: `type="EAIschema:eCodes"` where `eCodes` is another schema. When I compile it using xjc it returns:

> "Cannot resolve the name 'EAIschema:eCodes' to a(n) 'type definition' component"

I want to know how to solve this problem

Comment: Have you generated the classes for the other XSD? Where are theses classes located? In the same project?

Comment: Well I didn't but even when i force -nv to do not strictly check. it returns errors

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the error message, but it looks to me as if the JAXB classes for the other XSD were missing. If your XSD uses data structures of the other XSD then your JAXB classes will need those JAXB classes.

Solution: generate/ add the JAXB classes for the other XSD to your classpath.

If those classes are in a separate JAR, make sure it contains an episode file.

Comment: another question, is there is another way to convert xsd to java on runtime and not using the command?

Comment: What do you want to do with these classes if they are not available at compile time?

Comment: I a way to pull the xsd schema and then depend on this schema fills some values and generates xml

Comment: But how would you know what values to fill (what the elements and attributes mean), if you don't know the XSD at compile time?

Comment: I will represent it to the user and let him fill a tree and then fills it to the object and then XML

Answer (score 0):

When the XJC tool is converting the XML schema(s) to Java classes it will automatically pull in imported/included schemas based on their system id.  It those schemas are not available at the specified system id (or its not specified) then you could use an XML catalog.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html